# Switching column and row headers in DataGridView

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I have set up a `DataGridView` in part of my application as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

I'm attempting to databind this to a specified business object, and use it as an alternative `PropertyGrid` (there are a number of issues that make `PropertyGrid` inappropriate for my planned use).

The below view is built on-the-fly from a specified set of the business object's properties.

There are three area's I'm struggling with:

1. DataBinding - I want to bind this grid to a specified business object, for two-way databinding.
2. CellTemplate - I will need to have different cell templates on different rows, depending on the datatype of the property. TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, CheckBoxes, Date/Time Pickers.
3. Validation - `OnCellLeave`, I need to validate the value entered, and format the cell red = failed validation, blue = passed validation. Then when the user leaves the overall control, if there are blue cells, persist the object to DB, but if there are red cells, restore the object from DB. I already have this functionality implemented on other (traditional) `DataGridView`'s, and this description is just for info / context.

I have implemented all of the above in the traditional form (properties in column headers), but am having problems getting it working with the properties in the row headers, which is what I'm really after.

If anyone has implemented something like this, or can help, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.